# What happens when php code doesn't reach release-mysql-lock stage?

Tags: php, mysql

As an example, with this script;

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES mytest WRITE;");

for ($i = 1; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytest (Value, Value2, Value3) VALUES ($i, $i, $i);");
}

mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES;");
```

What would happen if the script timed out / the users computer crashed / whatever before the `UNLOCK TABLES` stage is reached? Will mysql "notice" the client requesting the lock has disconnected and release the lock appropriately, or will it be stuck infinitively?

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is does your sql engine support locking, first of all? .. and "infinitively"?

Comment: You might want to use `ignore_user_abort(true);` to ensure your script finishes no matter if the user aborts the request or disconnects for another reason.

Comment: @Blake What's wrong with [infinitively](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/infinitively)? And yes it supports locking.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Apparently that's not necessary, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: @natli "In grammar, infinitive is the name for certain verb forms that exist in many languages..." You wanted "infinitely." Just because a word exists, doesn't mean it's used properly.

Comment: @Blake So English isn't my first language.. who cares? Seriously, who are all these people pointing out grammar mistakes on the internet, I'll never get it. You know what I meant, so why does it bother you so much it's worth a mention? If it was with good intentions then thank you, but otherwise...

Comment: Grammar police exist to keep the internet from turning into a giant text message from a 13-year-old girl.

Comment: May I point out to you two that by bickering like this on a forum for  *programming* you are being no better than that 13 year old girl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) docs:

> If the connection for a client session terminates, whether normally or
>   abnormally, the server implicitly releases all table locks held by the
>   session (transactional and nontransactional). If the client
>   reconnects, the locks will no longer be in effect.

Comment: +1 Who knew it took 11.7k rep to learn how to google "mysql table lock" and read

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Awesome sarcasm, and I did google, but for a more specific phrase.

Comment: Actually it was "mysql lock tables". :)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/set-lock-wait-timeout-in-mysql has some good information as well